# Show that $\log(e^{x_1} + e^{x_2})$ is convex.

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Do I need to find Hessian matrix? or is there any other method ?

Comment: $\log$ is concave, not convex

Comment: [More general version here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/802445/147263)

Answer (score 1):

The function $\;f(x,y)=\log(e^x+e^y)\;$ is convex [iff](http://www.ee.ucla.edu/ee236b/lectures/functions.pdf) the function

$$\;g(t):=f(\vec x+t\vec y)=\log\left(e^{x_1+ty_1}+e^{x_2+ty_2}\right)\;$$ is convex, but:

$$\begin{align*}g'(t)&=\frac{y_1e^{x_1+ty_1}+y_2e^{x_2+ty_2}}{e^{x_1+ty_1}+e^{x_2+ty_2}}\\{}\\g''(t)&=\frac{\left(y_1^2e^{x_1+ty_1}+y_2^2e^{x_2+ty_2}\right)(e^{x_1+ty_1}+e^{x_2+ty_2})-(y_1e^{x_1+ty_1}+y_2e^{x_2+ty_2})^2}{(e^{x_1+ty_1}+e^{x_2+ty_2})^2}\end{align*}\;$$

Comment: I'm not sure $g(t)$ is correct.

Comment: Perhaps it is not, @RossB....what do you think it should be?

Comment: Wouldn't it be $\dfrac{y_1e^{x_1+ty_1}+y_2e^{x_2+ty_2}}{e^{x_1+ty_1}+e^{x_2+ty_2}}$?

Comment: Oh, you meant $\;g'(t)\;$....yes, you're right. Thanks and editing on its way.

Comment: can i show that Eigen values are positive semi-definite and that is why it is convex?

Comment: @RossB.can i show that Eigen values are positive semi-definite and that is why it is convex?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x_1,x_2)=\log\big(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2} \big)$. 
No you do not necessarily need to calculate the Hessian. You can prove that for every curve
$\alpha(t)=(x_1(t),x_2(t))$ such that $\alpha(0)=(x_1,x_2)$ for all $(x_1,x_2)$ and $t$
$$
g^{\prime\prime}(t)=(f\circ \alpha)^{\prime\prime}(t)\geq 0
$$
But calculating the Hessian of this function is not as laborious as well.We need prove that $\quad \forall v=(v_1,v_2)\in\mathbb{R}^2$
\begin{align}
v \cdot \mbox{Hess}f(x_1,x_2)\cdot v^T
=
&
\left[v_1,v_2 \right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1\partial x_1} 
&
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2\partial x_1} 
\\
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1\partial x_2} 
&
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2\partial x_2}
\end{array}
\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}v_1\\v_2 \end{array}\right]\geq 0,
\\
=&\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1\partial x_1}v_1v_1 +
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}v_1v_2 \\
+&\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}v_2v_1 +
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2\partial x_2}v_2v_2 \geq0
\end{align}
We have
\begin{align}
v \cdot \mbox{Hess}f(x_1,x_2)\cdot v^T
=
&
\left[v_1,v_2 \right]\cdot
\left[
\begin{array}{cc} 
\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}
&
-\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}} 
\\
-\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}
&
\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}
\end{array}
\right]
\cdot
\left[\begin{array}{c}v_1\\v_2 \end{array}\right]
\\
=&\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}\left(v_1^2-2v_1v_2+v_2^2 \right)
\\
=&
\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}\left(v_1-v_2 \right)^2\geq 0
\end{align}

Partial derivatives
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1\partial x_1} =
&
\frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_1\partial x_1}\log( e^{x_1}+e^{x_1})
=
\frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_1}\left(\frac{e^{x_1}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}\right)
\\
=
&
\frac{(e^{x_1})_{x_1}(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})-(e^{x_1})(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})_{x_1}}{(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})^2}
=
\frac{e^{x_1}e^{x_2}}{(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})^2}
\end{align}
analogously
$$
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2\partial x_2}=\frac{e^{x_1}e^{x_2}}{(e^{x_1}+e^{x_2})^2}
$$
and 
$$
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}=
\frac{\partial\, f(x_1,x_2)}{\partial x_1\partial x_2}  
=
\frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_2\partial x_1}\log( e^{x_1}+e^{x_1})
=
\frac{\partial\,}{\partial x_2}\left(\frac{e^{x_1}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}\right)
=
-\frac{e^{x_1}\cdot e^{x_2}}{e^{x_1}+e^{x_2}}
$$

Comment: Along these lines, a derivation for the convexity of the log-sum-exp function in general (i.e. summing $n$ exp's) using slightly more compact notation can also be found in "Convex Optimization" by Body & Vandenberghe.